# What is the authenticity of a narrative in which bells were ordered to be removed from camels during the Battle of Badr (Musnad Ahmad)?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

In the narrative Aisha RA reports that the Prophet ordered for bells to be removed from camels during the battle of Badr.

Arabic Version:

> #### عن عائشة أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم أمر بالأجراس أن تقطع من أعناق الإبل يوم بدر
>
> (احمد بن حنبل ، رقم ۲۵۲۰۷)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hadith is Sahih on the conditions of Bukhari and Muslim.

[Ibn Kathir](https://al-maktaba.org/book/4445/2354#p1):

> وهذا على شرط الصحيحين

[Haythami](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33855/1483#p17):

> ورجاله رجال الصحيح

[Ibn Hibban](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31691/9480#p1): (also see [Albani](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31591/9572#p1))

> (*Records it in his Sahih in كتاب السير*).

[Arnaa’oot](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25794/21266#p1):

> حديث صحيح، محمد بن جعفر- وإن سمع من سعيد (وهو ابن أبي عروبة) بعد
>   الاختلاط - قد توبع، وبقية رجاله ثقات رجال الشيخين

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to translate the rest, but do you mind translating Arnaa'oot's decision into English? Thank you.